# How to make relationship between [mail_Receivers] and [mail_Users_Messages_Mapped] tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am creating a database design for email system like gmail, hotmail, yahoo, but I am facing some problem regarding **[mail_Receivers]** table. I have to define this table's Id in **[mail_Users_Messages_Mapped]** table, but problem is that when receivers id would be more than one **Example**: 5 so 5 rows would be affected in database, Its mean 5 person have received this email, so how can I define **[mail_Receivers]** table Id in **[mail_Users_Messages_Mapped]** table?

Please help me,

Thanks in Advance.

My Code:

```
--1) 
CREATE TABLE [mail_Users]
    (
      [UserID] INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [UserEmail] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      [PASSWORD] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      [FirstName] NVARCHAR(50),
      [LastName] NVARCHAR(50)
    )
--2)
CREATE TABLE [mail_Messages]
    (
      [MessageID] INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [Subject] NVARCHAR(MAX),
      [Body] NVARCHAR(MAX),
      [Date] DATETIME,
    )
--3)
CREATE TABLE [mail_Receivers]
(
    [ReceiverId] INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ReceiverEmail] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
)
--4)
CREATE TABLE [mail_MessagePlaceHolders]
    (
      [PlaceHolderID] INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [PlaceHolder] NVARCHAR(255)--For example: InBox, SentItems, Draft, Trash, Spam 
    )

    /*
     *  Custom Implementation   
     */
--5)
CREATE TABLE [mail_Users_Attachments]
    (
        [AttachmentId] INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
        [AttachmentName] NVARCHAR(255),
        [AttachmentUri] NVARCHAR(255),
        [MessageId] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [mail_Messages]([MessageID]) NOT NULL
    )

    /*
     * End
     */
--6)
CREATE TABLE [mail_Users_Messages_Mapped]
    (
        [UserID] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [mail_Users]([UserID]) NOT NULL,
        [MessageID] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [mail_Messages]([MessageID]) NOT NULL,
        [ReceiverId] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [mail_ReceiverId]([ReceiverId]) NOT NULL,
        [PlaceHolderID] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [mail_MessagePlaceHolders]([PlaceHolderID]) NOT NULL,
        [AttachmentId] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [mail_Users_Attachments]([AttachmentId]),
        [IsRead] BIT,
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a many to many mapping table. This table holds the mesaage_id and receiver_id like this:

```
message_id receiver_id
1          1
1          2
1          3
2          1
3          2
```